# Strong and Weak events

Tags: c#, events

My understanding of events is having a list pointing to the delegate handlers, and whenever a publish is triggered, the aggregator loops through the list to invoke the ref pointers to the handlers.

I have also read about strong and weak events on many places but I don't exactly understand what they are. 
What are strong and weak events? What are their differences and their usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically weak events are "normal events" registered using "weak references"... mostly "weak events" are used when building/implementing a control to avoid potential memory leaks since "strong events" (i.e. strong references) have an impact on lifetime...

For a full explanation with sample source and references see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the link. In the case of my implementation described in the question, having a list of pointers to the delegate handlers, would this be a a case of "weak" or "strong" events?

Comment: that is strong... please follow the link... it is described very clearly what the differences are...